# How to change the package name in android in Java Generated Files

Tags: android, android-studio

I am pretty new to android.

I changed the package name of my project and after that i can't build the project.

Its giving me an error that package name not found.

But the file in which i am getting this error is an auto-generated file .

So even if I change the package name there it gets undone upon build.

Any help is highly appreciated.

BTW its my first ask on stack overflow.

Comment: @idrisjafer actually i knew how to change the package name but i forgot to clean the project afterwards. I came to knew that from the answer below. BTW thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you rename the package name?
You can `clean project` then `rebuild project` from the build menu.